# Bulk Move operation not working in wagtail 4.2.4

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have recently upgraded my Wagtail from v3.0 to v4.2.4 post which when I am trying to perform a bulk operation of 'Move' on multiple pages, I am getting an error as below

> DoesNotExist at /cms/admin/bulk/wagtailcore/page/move/
> GenericIndexPage matching query does not exist.

This issue is only for pages that are created and are instances or subpages of a particular parent page.
I referred to [the issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/10600) on Github which suggests to remove a line from move.py but this would be an issue since these files are not tracked and will be changed during wagtail upgrade process.